# Is there a way to select on a value attached by .data()?

Tags: jquery

Background: I'm performing an upgrade on an existing photo gallery plug-in which displays a large image in the center and progressively smaller images off to either side.

So my question is this:  I'm setting some data on each image that gives the image's index, the index of the next image, and the index of the previous image, like so:

```
$(this).data('index', i).data('prev', i - 1).data('next', i + 1);
```

Later on, I'd like to be able to select an image based on its index.  I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('[data-index=' + index + ']');
```

Is there a way to select an element based on a piece of data attached with `.data()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$('*').filter(function() { return $.data(this, 'index') == index; })
```

However, `*` is **very expensive**, as it runs this filter on all elements, please use a more specific selector to start with.

Comment: Sweet!  So then something like `$('img').filter(function() { return $.data(this, 'index') == index; })` should work, and be more efficient than using `*`.

Comment: If there are lots of elements on the page, then yes, ridiculously inefficient. jQuery has to sift through every single element on the page and test each and every one this way.  If you narrow the selector down like he said, its ok.

Comment: @Ender - yup, exactly.  If you have *lots* of elements, there's actually a completely backwards way to go about it, but try that first - since it's much simpler and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly alternative approach:

Assuming the images are in a series in the HTML, why not just do something like this?

`$('#images img').eq(index)`